# do i need to rebuild java projects everytime I pull it from a mercurial repository?

Tags: java, mercurial, tortoisehg

My co-workers have a Java project on Bitbucket. recently I need to run their project. SO I use TortoiseHg to pull the project. Should I rebuild the whole project which consists of 6 sub-projects every time I pull the project codes from the repository, assuming there're changes in the codes?

Comment: Oh MongoDB is the database they use in this project.

Comment: There should be a project file or build script that already takes care of recompiling classes that are older than the corresponding source file, so you should not have to do a clean rebuild each time.

Comment: Removed 'mongoDb' tag, there's nothing about mongoDb in the question body. Added 'mercurial' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your co-workers have multiple projects in one repo which is not the intended use of mercurial ([See One Project One Repository: Mercurial Used Right](http://www.webdevelopment.nicholastuck.com/tools/one-project-one-repository-mercurial-used-right/))

Since you are most likely not going to get them to fix that anytime soon you probably are safest rebuilding the entire all projects if they don't take too long.

Otherwise what you can do is 
`hg pull` 
 `hg status --rev x:tip` 
This is the status between the revision you built last (replace `x` with this number) and tip.  This should show you all the files that changed since you last built.  Now you can see which projects those are in, then only build the changed projects.